# Java - Referencing an object with a variable

Tags: java, object

I am trying to instantiate an object from within an if statement, basically an object when the user wants to create one. If the same code is being executed (with different arguments) then the reference to the object will be the same so…

Can you reference the object from a different variable, for example a unique id that is created in the constructor for the object?

```
    Test test1 = null;
    if (run == true){
       test1 = new Test(argument1);
       test1 = test1.id;
       }
```

I am inexperienced, but basically want a variable from the object to then point at that object, so it does not get overwritten when a new object is instantiated from the code being executed again.

Thanks

Comment: Is the `id` field in the `Test` class an instance of `Test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use something like an array here

```
int count = 0;
    Test[] tests = new Test[10];

    if(run == true){
        tests[count] = new Solution(argument1);
        count++;
    }
```

In this case we are making slots for 10 objects, really any number can go inside where that 10 is.  It also might be a good idea to use something like an ArrayList if your not sure how many objects you need to make.

To get an element from the array and use the object we can simply just use the name of the array followed by the spot in the array where it is located.

```
tests[0].someMethod() //will call the method on the object at index 0
```

Remember arrays start counting at zero so if you want the 2nd element you have to ask for the element at index 1.

Comment: Thank you, that suits what I wanted to do. Now I know you can't just dynamically reference instances...

Answer (score 1):

I get the sense that you're overcompensating for a scenario which wouldn't normally occur in Java.

To answer the question directly:  you wouldn't be able to use the ID of an object to refer to the object later unless you had a data structure (like a `Map<Integer, Test>`) keeping track of those instances.

In the scenario you illustrate, the only way that `test1` is not `null` is if your test condition passes.  Outside of that, it stands a chance of being `null` and causing runtime issues later.  Further, the reassignment to `test1` would fail if `test1.id` is not also an instance of `Test`.

Comment: Ok thanks, and is a data structure /map a practical thing to use?

Comment: I can't say so definitively as it's unclear as to what you're attempting to accomplish here.

Comment: Also, I declared it null so it had a wider scope than the if, I dont know another way because I wanted the object later on.

Comment: So this is what I mean - it's unclear why you would do this.  You likely received a compilation error for declaring it but not initializing it.  The question I have for you then is:  would it be possible for this object to be initialized in any other approach?

Comment: Possibly. I am unsure as I'm learning.  All I would like to do is initialize objects on user demand with arguments they input. There is probably a better way not using if conditions.

Comment: I may have to post a new question about this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically name variables in Java. May i suggest creating a `List` of `Test` variables? Every time the loop executes, add the variable to the `List`. This way you have a reference to all the objects that have been created.

Answer (score 0):

The instance won't be overwritten when you create a new instance, only your reference to the object will be overwritten. If you want to manage multiple instances of the object, you'll have to keep track of your references to them. You could keep an array of object references or collection of object references in your build function. Alternately, you could return the object reference to the caller and keep track of it there.